# Trying to cycle images but not updating after first click

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

It also increments up and down at random intervals. I'm new to javascript and can't figure out what's wrong with it.

```
var image = 1;

function nextI() {
  image = image + 1;
  console.log(image);
  if (image = 2) {
    document.getElementById("feature").src = "lazD.jpeg";
  } else if (image = 1) {
    document.getElementById("feature").src = "lazC.jpeg";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("feature").src = "lazH.jpeg";
  }
}

function prevI() {
  image = image - 1;
  console.log(image);
  if (image = 2) {
    document.getElementById("feature").src = "lazD.jpeg";
  } else if (image = 1) {
    document.getElementById("feature").src = "lazC.jpeg";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("feature").src = "lazH.jpeg";
  }
}
```

Comment: you need `if (image == 2)`, comparisons use `==` or `===`

Comment: Your if statements aren't corret. You should use == in place of =, because = always returns true AND associate the value of yout image to 2. The == is the comparison operator.

Comment: Can you add the code that's calling these functions?